# Clone from github to Unity not working as intended

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, version-control

I am trying to help a friend of mine on his unity project, but I can't clone his project properly. The project I get doesn't have any scenes and no sln file. Does anybody know a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are using a CI server you can get away without checking these files in since Unity re-creates them when you open the Unity project.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, it seems like your friend hasn't put the scenes and the sln file in his project. Check the repository on github to see if they are in there. If not, ask him to put them in there, but if so it's probably a problem with Git.

Also, how are you cloning it?